# Getting stack overflow error when running recursive linear search

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, linear-search

I realize that a binary search would be much more efficient and I even have one working but I'm required to write a recursive linear search for a lab.
i keep getting stack overflow on the method `linSearch()`, specifically on line 33.

I'm required to search arrays as big as 1,280,000.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class linSearch {    
    public static void main(String[] args){
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("enter size");
       int size = in.nextInt();
       System.out.println("enter numb");
       double numb = in.nextDouble();
       double [] array = new double[size];
       for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
          for(int j = 0; j < size-1; j++){
              double random = (int)(Math.random() * 1000000);
              array[j] = (double)(random / 100);
          }
          int position = linSearch(array, numb, 0);
          if(position == -1){
              System.out.println("the term was not found");
         }
        else{
            System.out.println("the term was found");
        }
    }
}
public static int linSearch(double[] array, double key, int counter){
    if(counter == array.length){
        return -1;
    }
        if(array[counter] == key){
            return counter;
        }
        else{
            counter += 1;
            return linSearch(array, key, counter);  //error occurs here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your stack isn't big enough to hold 1,280,000 stack frames. You need to write an iterative version of the algorithm or implement an binary search. A binary search would only require a stack log2(1280000) = 20 frames deep.

Comment: A linear search is a very poor candidate for a recursive solution.  You are unlikely to be able to write a working program that way if it needs to handle inputs as large as you say.  Perform an iterative linear search instead.

Comment: thank you for your responses but the thing is this lab requires a recursive linear search i can't get around that

Comment: Well, besides binary searches requiring ordered inputs... note that many non-updating recursive algorithms (such as searches) can be somewhat trivially parallelized.  What I would have assumed is that after getting `n` number of frames deep, it changes to a non-recursive version, in a divide-and-conquer approach (I have a feeling this is what @axblount really meant).  You can only parallelize about `2x + 1` tasks (where `x` is the number of processors available), so go that deep, or until there's 8 elements to search.  Oh, you might find it worthwhile to break up the main method some too.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I think he should just use a danged for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be lucky if your stack could hold 15000 interative call to itself never mind 128,000
However If you have verified that the recursion is implemented correctly, you can increase the stack’s size, in order to allow a larger number of invocations. Depending on the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) installed, the default thread stack size may equal to either 512KB, or 1MB.

**However You can increase the thread stack size using the -Xss flag. This flag can be specified either via the project’s configuration, or via the command line.**

[Click & Follow Guide Here](http://crunchify.com/jvm-tuning-heapsize-stacksize-garbage-collection-fundamental/)

Hope this helps